# Powershell script that gets the list of Windows VMs with a specific tag

Tags: azure, powershell, cloud

using powershell, I need to get a list of Windows VMs of all subscriptions within a tenant. I need only the VMs with a tag ApplicationName that contains PROD in its value.

Here is my current script:

```
# Get resource groups with the specified tag
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.Tags -ne $null -and $_.Tags['ApplicationName'] -like "*PROD*" }
 
# Create an array to store the results
$results = @()
 
# Iterate through each resource group
foreach ($group in $resourceGroups) {
    $groupName = $group.ResourceGroupName
    $vms = Get-AzVM

    foreach ($vm in $vms) {

        if ($vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.OSType -eq "Windows") {

            $result = [ordered]@{
                'VM Name' = $vm.Name
                'Subscription' = $group.Subscription
                'Resource Group' = $groupName
                'Location' = $vm.Location
                'Publisher' = $vm.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Publisher
                'Plan' = $vm.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Sku
                'Offer' = $vm.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Offer
            }
        $results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $result
        }  
    }
}

# Output the results in a table format
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize
 
# Export the results to a CSV file
$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXX\WindowsVMsList.csv" -NoTypeInformation
 
Write-Output "Script execution completed."
```

There are 2 issues in the script output, subsription column is blank and the ApplicationName tag filter is not taked in consideration.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get a list of Windows VMs of all subscriptions within a tenant. I need only the VMs with a tag ApplicationName that contains PROD in its value.

Here is the updated `PowerShell` script to fetch all `VMs` in the **tenant** that are tagged with the **specified tags**.

```
$vmList = @()

$sub = Get-AzSubscription

foreach ($subnames in $sub) {
  $subid = $subnames.Id
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subId
    $vms = Get-AzVM | Where-Object { $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType -eq "Windows" -and $_.Tags["ApplicationName"] -like "*PROD*" }
    foreach ($vm in $vms) {
       $subId = $vm.Id.Split('/')[2]
        $vmList += [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $vm.Name
            SubscriptionID = $subId
            ResourceGroup = $vm.ResourceGroupName
            Location = $vm.Location
            OsProfile = $vm.OsProfile
            VMTags = $vm.Tags
        }
    }
}
$vmList 

$vmList | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\XXXXX\WindowsVMsList.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Working, thanks! Do you have an idea why mine didnt take filter results based on tag?